# App good with one new intent but when I tap on same link again. Get error: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW

Tags: android, android-intent, progressive-web-apps, trusted-web-activity, onnewintent

I use Intent to send message from website to Progressive Web App. Just to show admob ads in native code. Best solution what I found is add code to

```
 override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent)
        showInterstatial();
```

Simple and work but only one time. As I understand when I use onNewIntent it is replace onCreate and not register activity where `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` and

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data android:scheme="octoads"/>
</intent-filter>
```

When I use more then one time this intent I got this error:

````
Process: online.octonauts.creaturer, PID: 709
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=octoads://octon.online?m=inter pkg=com.android.chrome (has extras) }
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2100)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1747)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5465)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5423)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5809)
        at androidx.core.content.ContextCompat$Api16Impl.startActivity(ContextCompat.java:830)
        at androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.startActivity(ContextCompat.java:279)
        at androidx.browser.trusted.TrustedWebActivityIntent.launchTrustedWebActivity(TrustedWebActivityIntent.java:48)
        at com.google.androidbrowserhelper.trusted.TwaLauncher.launchWhenSplashScreenReady(TwaLauncher.java:273)
        at com.google.androidbrowserhelper.trusted.TwaLauncher.lambda$launchWhenSessionEstablished$4$com-google-androidbrowserhelper-trusted-TwaLauncher(TwaLauncher.java:257)
        at com.google.androidbrowserhelper.trusted.TwaLauncher$$ExternalSyntheticLambda3.run(Unknown Source:6)
        at com.google.androidbrowserhelper.trusted.splashscreens.PwaWrapperSplashScreenStrategy.lambda$onSplashImageTransferred$1$com-google-androidbrowserhelper-trusted-splashscreens-PwaWrapperSplashScreenStrategy(PwaWrapperSplashScreenStrategy.java:208)
        at com.google.androidbrowserhelper.trusted.splashscreens.PwaWrapperSplashScreenStrategy$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.google.androidbrowserhelper.trusted.splashscreens.PwaWrapperSplashScreenStrategy.runWhenEnterAnimationComplete(PwaWrapperSplashScreenStrategy.java:215)
        at com.google.androidbrowserhelper.trusted.splashscreens.PwaWrapperSplashScreenStrategy.onSplashImageTransferred(PwaWrapperSplashScreenStrategy.java:207)
        at com.google.androidbrowserhelper.trusted.splashscreens.PwaWrapperSplashScreenStrategy.lambda$configureTwaBuilder$0$com-google-androidbrowserhelper-trusted-splashscreens-PwaWrapperSplashScreenStrategy(PwaWrapperSplashScreenStrategy.java:195)
        at com.google.androidbrowserhelper.trusted.splashscreens.PwaWrapperSplashScreenStrategy$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onFinished(Unknown Source:6)
        at com.google.androidbrowserhelper.trusted.splashscreens.SplashImageTransferTask$1.onPostExecute(SplashImageTransferTask.java:144)
        at com.google.androidbrowserhelper.trusted.splashscreens.SplashImageTransferTask$1.onPostExecute(SplashImageTransferTask.java:91)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:771)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$900(AsyncTask.java:199)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:788)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8582)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:563)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1133)
```
````